# website is still in localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wampserver

I upload my website to the server and I changed the website url and home from localhost to mysite url. But it still is in localhost if I turned off wampserver it won't show the website. Just show me when wamp server is on.

By the way I use wordpress cms.

What should I do?

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the following steps:

1. If you are using a custom theme, copy that folder to your host
2. Copy your uploads folder (if you are using default setting that would be `/PATH_TO_WORDPRESS/wp-content/uploads`)
3. Backup your database, I use command line: `mysqldump --host=localhost --user=[your mysql username] -p [your database] > transfer.sql`  So if your username is user1 and your database name is database1 the command would be `mysqldump --host=localhost --user=user1 -p database1 > transfer.sql`  You could name transfer.sql whatever you want, but it must end .sql.
4. Copy, or preferably rsync your database to your server
5. Load your database to your server using this command: `mysql --host=[whatever your host is] --user=[your user name] -p [your database] < transfer.sql`  This will refresh your site with the latest posts and content.
6. Go get the [search and replace tool](http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) (this will do what octav is telling you to do in his answer - I prefer to use the tool because it prevents you from messing up your database, do not be like me and learn the hard way, use this tool) and place it somewhere in your wordpress installation.  I would actually do this locally before I copy the database to the server, it is more secure that way.  Make sure to rename the file as the site tells you to.  In your web browser type the path to that php file.  Follow the instructions until you get to the search and replace page.  Place localhost/path in the search and your URL in the replace.

Your site should be good to go.  Is your local machine Windows or Mac/Linux?  The instructions for transferring files are a little different.  Let me know and I will update accordingly.

Oh and do not forget to look at WordPress's codex for moving your site: [Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Answer (score 2):

When I move a website from localhost to live, I usually use 4 queries to update the database. Before using them, you need to:

1. replace `wp_` with the table prefix you are using (check the `wp-config.php` file and look for `$table_prefix  = 'wp_';`)
2. replace `old-domain.com` with `localhost` (or `localhost/wordpress` if you installed your website in `http://localhost/wordpress`)
3. replace `new-domain.com` with your domain name.

The SQL queries:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, "old-domain.com", "new-domain.com") WHERE option_value LIKE '%old-domain.com%';
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, "old-domain.com", "new-domain.com") WHERE post_content LIKE '%old-domain.com%';
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE(guid, "old-domain.com", "new-domain.com") WHERE guid LIKE '%old-domain.com%';
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, "old-domain.com", "new-domain.com") WHERE meta_value LIKE '%old-domain.com%';
```